# Is Gattica gem (RoR) still maintained/supported?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics-api, garb-gem

I would like to start reading some Google Analytics (GA) data in my RoR project, and from what I discovered the 2 main tools for that are Gattica and Garb.

Gattica seems to be more easy and simpler to use, however I'm concerned that it haven't been update for quite a long time, and it's documentation haven't been updated for 4 years. So I have doubts about using this.

- Is it is still working well? Will it support the GA's latest improvements (I don't want to re-code my work in a few months for vain)?
- Also, it's documentation says that it doens't support more than the first 1000 results (there is a GA API for stating from which result to begin, but Gattica's didn't implement that "yet") - was that ever implemented or will be?

By the way, have Garb been changed to be Legato?

Comment: At this point you'd have to consider Gattica abandonware, and Garb's README says it has been moved to Legato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll definitely want to use the Legato gem (https://github.com/tpitale/legato) - which indeed is Garb reincarnated. Gattica is unmaintained and Garb tells people to use Legato; Garb is only being maintained for those unable (for whatever reason) to switch to Legato. So Legato is your safest bet.

Comment: Thanks. I had the feeling that this is the answer :)

Comment: Hey! Yeah, sorry about the weirdness. Legato is essentially Garb+1. Let me know if you have any questions on Legato!

Answer (score 0):

Try This, Though last commit was 2 years back, Still I found it Helpful.

https://github.com/chrisle/gattica